# Load Async reducers and sagas in react-boilerplate with React router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-boilerplate

I am looking at migrating a project to the latest react-boilerplate version and many modules have changed. I am having trouble with React router v4 to play with my reducers and sagas. I looked at [Dynamically load redux reducers with react router 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988229/dynamically-load-redux-reducers-with-react-router-4)
and I am getting the following error now: 
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

> Check the render method of `withReducer(Component)`.
>       in withReducer(Component) (created by Route)
>       in Route (created by App)
>       in Switch (created by App)
>       in div (created by App)
>       in App (created by Connect(App))
>       in Connect(App) (created by Route)
>       in Route (created by withRouter(Connect(App)))
>       in withRouter(Connect(App))
>       in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>       in BrowserRouter
>       in IntlProvider (created by LanguageProvider)
>       in LanguageProvider (created by Connect(LanguageProvider))
>       in Connect(LanguageProvider)
>       in Provider

My code is slightly different to the example I followed because I am adding withRouter:

```
const withConnect = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps));

const addHelpReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'help', reducer: helpReducer });

export default compose(
    addHelpReducer,
    withConnect
  )(Help);
```

injectReducer comes from the react-boilerplate utils file, I have not modified that file or the configureStore file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this:

```
export default compose(
    withRouter,
    withReducer,
    withSaga,
    withConnect
  )(Help);
```

Although I now moved into a different issue. Closing this one.